# Importance of Cocos2D CCScenes?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, layer

I recently followed Ray Wenderlich's Cocos2D tutorial for putting Cocos2D in a UIKit app. I am currently only using Cocos2D in only one of my UIViews. In the tutorial he uses a CCScene which is a specific .h and .m class in the project. In the scene is some code which I do not know the important of either. I must say that I am new to Cocos2D and I am wondering what is the point of a CCScene? Do I need to use it in my situation? And if so, how?

Thanks!

**Edit1**: Is this correct? I am also adding a simple game loop so should I do it in the way I am doing it below or should I use CADisplayLink?

```
//Cocos2D methods
-(id) init {
    if((self=[super init]))
    {
        CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
        CCLayer *layer = [CCLayer node];
        [scene addChild:layer];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:scene];
        [self performSelector:@selector(cocosgameLoop:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1/60.0f];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)cocosgameLoop:(ccTime)dT {
    //Check for collisions here and add gravity, etc....
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
}
//
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CCScene is a root node in a scene graph. A node that have no parents. CCDirector operates with CCScenes only. Read this for more information: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_3._menus_and_scenes

**ANSWER TO YOUR COMMENT**

Actually you don't have to understand how CCScene is implemented. But if you want something to be rendered with cocos2d you have to create a CCScene and pass it to CCDirector. The common way is:

```
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
CCLayer *layer = [CCLayer node];
[scene addChild:layer];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:scene];
```

Usually you have to subclass a CCLayer and reimplement `init` method to add your staff (sprites for example). Take a look at programming guide for more more detailed answer:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:index

Comment: Hmm interesting. So does that mean in my case I need a CCScene then? If so, would kind of code would be in it?

Comment: Ah ok so that code would go inside inside a init method? And also in that init method, would go code to get my characters and other game sprites into position?
Also what do you mean by subclassing CCLayer? Sorry for all the questions, its just that I'm new to this!
Thanks!

Comment: @MyApps:read about inheritance in objective-c. It's hard to explain in a few words. Yes, you can position your sprite in the init method. You can also register a function that will be called every frame (take a look at programming guide). You can update your sprite positions there

Comment: Alright I googled it and I understand it a bit more but I updated my original post with the current code I have. Is that what it is supposed to look like? Also can we take this to a chat messenger? I need help with my game and ill pay just to have you give me some tips on what to do and how to implement it etc...

Comment: @MyApps: find me in skype: nitrogen0119882006